# Haystack and solr : new records not indexed

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am implementing search feature with Django + haystack + Solr.

Initially i had 3 records and executed 'manage.py rebuild_index' command and it indexed 3 records. These records started showing in results. From Admin console, I added a new record. This is not showing up in the search results.

But when execute, 'manage.py rebuild_index' command once again, it says indexing 4 records and  then the new record shows up in the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `SearchIndex` does not automatically index new items. This means you need to periodically call `update_index` to keep in the Solr index current.

Another option is to use the `RealTimeSearchIndex` which does add items to the search index as they are created. http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/searchindex_api.html#realtimesearchindex

A third option is to use a `QueuedSearchIndex` as recommended in the Haystack best practices. For this you can see these two additional applications: https://github.com/toastdriven/queued_search or https://github.com/ennio/celery-haystack.